# Eucalyptus: What root device name should I use to register a Windows EBS-backed image?

Tags: windows, cloud, eucalyptus

I would like to create an EBS-backed Windows image in Eucalyptus 3.4.

https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#image-guide/img_task_create_bfebs_image.html

I have reached the last step, registering the snapshot:

```
euca-register --name <image-name> --snapshot <snapshot-id> --root-device-name <device>
```

What should the value of <device> be?

All the examples I have found via searching have been Unix examples, e.g.

```
/dev/sda
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--root-device-name should be /dev/sda only but remember to give the following options.

```
--kernel windows
```